# WSO2 APIM v1.9.0 integration with an External LDAP

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

All,

Has anyone had success with integrating APIM v1.9.0 with an external LDAP? If so, can you please explain how the configuration should be modified. I'm not having any luck on my end.

Thanks,
Hunter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find many user store managers in the `user-mgt.xml` file. For the purposes of this example, we are going to use the `ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager`.

You have to commented out other userstore managers.

If your requirement is to do both read and write operations, then use the `ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager` or if your willing to use an Active Directory Domain Service (AD DS) or Active Directory Lightweight Directory Service (AD LDS), then use the `ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager`.

The following is a sample user store manager configuration.

```
<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager">
  <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
  <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://localhost:1389</Property>
  <Property  name="ConnectionName">cn=ldapuser+sn=abcd,cn=users,ou=depart,dc=abc,dc=com</Property>
  <Property name="ConnectionPassword">12345</Property>
  <Property name="UserSearchBase">cn=users,ou=depart,dc=abc,dc=com</Property>
  <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=person)</Property>
  <Property name="UserNameAttribute">cn</Property>
  <Property name="ReadLDAPGroups">false</Property>
  <Property name="GroupSearchBase">cn=users,ou=depart,dc=abc,dc=com</Property>
  <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=groupOfNames)</Property>
  <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
  <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
  <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
  <Property name="ReplaceEscapeCharactersAtUserLogin">true</Property>
  ..................
</UserStoreManager>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding Abirmaran....I did edit this file but I'm receiving errors when I restart APIM. The errors are as follows: 1. LDAP: error code 49. There is also an Error code 32 - No such Object.

Comment: Also, while looking the /wso2/wso2am-1.9.0/bin/server.out log, there are "RealmConfigXMLProcessor" errors. "Required property DomainName missing in secondary user store. Skip adding the user store.

Comment: When enabling this user store manager, you need to comment out the default one, which is the JDBCUserStoreManager. Also, it seems you might have done something wrong when enabling i.e. uncommenting the ldap related configs.

Comment: Thank you for responding Amila. By the way, I'm trying to authenticate to a read-only LDAP. When I comment out the default userstore, I can no longer access the UI. Are there other changes that are required other than just updating the ReadOnly LDAP userstore?

Comment: The default userstore is based on JDBC, you have to commented out it and enable read-only LDAP.

Comment: I have commented out the JDC Userstore and uncommented the read-only LDAP Userstore. I am receiving an LDAP error: 49 code

Comment: You need to check what's that LDAP error code means? It's a issue in LDAP and the user.

Comment: The LDAP error states "Invalid Credentials". I'm working with the support team of the external LDAP system. However, when I comment out the JDBC section and uncomment the Read-only LDAP, the APIM URL doesn't connect with the process is started. Is this because of the LDAP issue or is there something else within APIM that is misconfigured?

Comment: What do you mean by APIM URL doesn't connect?

Comment: I am unable to access the API endpoint when I comment out the JDBC and uncomment the LDAP userstore sections. The error that I continue to get is "ERROR - LDAPConnectionContxt Error obtaining connection. Trying again to get connection.....javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - LDAP Error 49 : [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]

Comment: I am now past the LDAP invalid credentials error. My user account had to be re-created and wso2 was able to connect. Now, I cannot log into the wso2 APIM. Should the local admin account still work?

Comment: Yes, default admin user account should work, and you have to login through that and assign necessary permissions for your LDAP user groups, so they can login to API Manager/publisher/store.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I was able to successfully connect to my customer's LDAP and retrieve their users. The issues that I ran into were solely related to the LDAP bind account that was created for me to use. Upon having a new account created, I was able to use it to connect. So, if I didn't have an account problem, the external ldap connection would have worked initially. However, it would be good to mention something about updating the /etc/openldap/ldap.conf file as this was needed to make the connection.

Comment: The reason I couldn't log into the APIM UI was because there were multiple instances of the wso2server running which filled up memory. I needed to reboot my server, restart MySQL and I was able to login and retrieve the ldap users. Once again, thanks for all the support.